# Using input from the user in another file php

Tags: php, html

I wan't to use the input from the user inside another file. Because now I can't use the input from the user(inside the send.php file) because I don't know how to get those input's.

THIS IS MY INDEX.PHP :

```
<form> 
<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username....">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password....">
<br>
<br>
<div class="knop">
<a href="send.php">Inloggen</a>
</form>
```

My send.php :

```
include("index.php");

$username = "Username: ";
$us = $_POST['Username']; // I wan't to get the input that the user gave inside the index.php
$password = "Password: ";
$pass = $_POST['Password']; // I wan't to get the input that the user gave inside the index.php
```

Comment: Please read more about [forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), especially the `action` and `method` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

simply just set an action attribute and the HTTP method in your form tag , and  you shouldn't use the href attribute, because it just because it will only redirect you to another page without sending the data, use the button tag with submit attribute instead

```
<form action="path/to/send.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username....">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password....">
<br>
<br>
<div class="knop">
<button type="submit">Inloggen<button/>
</form>
```

now you can retrieve the data with `$_POST['Password']` and `$_POST['Username']` in your `send.php`,

and you also don't have to `include` your index.php in send.php.

I thought before you working with PHP and HTML form, you need to read more about PHP and HTML